# Is there a way in SQLServer to generate an insert from another insert statement without using functions?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, user-defined-functions

I have a translation table that is related to almost every table in the database. I need to populate this table everytime. I make an insert in one of this tables. In ORACLE I did this way:

```
 INSERT  INTO M_ANYTABLE
         ( ID_ANYTABLE ,
           TEXT ,
           DATE ,
           TRANS_ID

 )

 VALUES  ( 'PEPE' ,
           'PEPE' ,
           SYSDATE ,
           FN_TRD_NOCOMMIT('TEXT TRANSLATE')
         );
```

Function FN_TRD_NOCOMMIT make the inserts in translations table.

I can't replicate this in SQLServer because functions cannot change the Database in any way. I fixed this making Triggers (one for each Table). Although I know is not a elegant solution.

What I am asking is if anyone can come with a better way of making inserts through the original insert statement (above) or any other solution that you have deployed for making inserts through a function or whatever doesn't imply using one trigger for each Table. Any ideas?

I hope I made my point correctly. Sorry in case of bad English. Thanks in advance.

Comment: means you need to insert in master and child table in a single unit of work. Then, are you using procedure? or insert query

Comment: Yes, I need an insert query solution if it´s possible.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understood you right, but you can use OUTPUT for thet:

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
    ID_ANYTABLE VARCHAR(123),
           TEXT VARCHAR(123) ,
           DATE DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE #test2
(
    ID_ANYTABLE VARCHAR(123),
           TEXT VARCHAR(123) ,
           DATE DATETIME
)

 INSERT  INTO #test
         ( ID_ANYTABLE ,
           TEXT ,
           DATE   
         )  
 OUTPUT INSERTED.ID_ANYTABLE, INSERTED.TEXT, INSERTED.DATE INTO    #test2      
 VALUES  ( 'PEPE' ,
           'PEPE' ,
           GETDATE() 
         );

SELECT * FROM #test
SELECT * FROM #test2
```

Comment: I don't think `output` supports inserting into multiple tables?

Comment: The OP said "making Triggers (one for each Table)" but that doesn't really say if he's trying to insert into multiple tables. If it's just a single one (like a log table) your solution might work, +1

Answer (score 0):

Use a SQL Server [stored procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) instead of a function. Stored procedures can insert and update as many tables as you like:

```
create procedure dbo.SpInsertStuff(@par1 varchar(max))
as
insert into table1 (col1) values (@par1);
insert into table2 (col1) values (@par1);
insert into table3 (col1) values (@par1);
go
exec dbo.SpInsertStuff('Hello World!');
```

Triggers add implicit complexity: they do things in a usually invisible and unexpected way. I'd stay away from triggers.

Answer (score 0):

So whenever you want to insert in master-child relation and work as a single unit of work, first you need to use `transaction` and use `indentity` option.

There is `@@identity`  and `Scope_identity`. Both are use to capture the last inserted pk-id, only difference is second used in transaction level.

So your query would be. whenever you get error it will rollback else commit and give the result.

```
create procedure procedurename
(
    --parmater list
)
as 
begin
declare @getmasterid int 
    begin tran
    BEGIN TRY
        insert into tblMaster 
        (
        )
        values
        ()

        select @getmasterid = SCOPE_IDENTITY

        insert into tblchildtable
        (
        ..,masterid,..  
        )
        values
        ( 
        ..,@getmasterid,..
        )

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT 
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
            ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
            ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
            ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
            ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
            ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END CATCH;

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;

end
```